# How do I close the Excel background process with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, taskmanager

I have looked at other questions similar to mine and it seems like I am missing something. I have isolated my code to isolate the problem. My code is below. I am simply opening an Excel workbook and closing it. **For some reason, the background Excel process in Task Manager lingers and I cannot close it with VBA code and have to do it manually.** I have stepped through the code and the background process opens after line 3 is executed. When I have lines 4-6 commented out, the background process closes fine. I have seen lines of code that opens a command prompt to kill the process but that closes all Excel workbooks open as opposed to just the active workbook.

```
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oWB As Object
    
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Automation\IO List.xlsm")
    
oWB.Close True
Set oWB = Nothing
    
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

[Task manager processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfb7S.png)

Comment: Does anything in the workbook you open change when it's opened? For example, a formula is updated? Have you tried making the instance of Excel you are creating  visible?

Comment: Not in this set of code. I just created this to find when the problem area may be. I have tested it and the workbook opens successfully. I am able to read and write to it.

Comment: It's the closing of the workbook that could be the problem, for example if the workbook is changed when you try and close the workbook you would get a save dialog. If you then proceed, in your code, to quit Excel you will end up with a 'ghost' instance of Excel.

Comment: Make the created Excel instance visible and that might give you some ideas as to why it's not closing.

Comment: I have modified the code to include oExcel.Visible = True after setting oExcel. After the window becomes visible, the background process goes away. It stays closed until oExcel.Quit is executed, then the background process returns...and remains. I want to also note that once opened, no changes were made and no prompt to save appeared.

Comment: Your code works for me so it is your environment. Are there any other macros that run in that file.

Comment: PS It could be simplified to `GetObject("C:\Automation\IO List.xlsm")`. All other lines are optional or unnecessary. At every `End Sub` or `End Function` all objects are set to nothing.

Comment: I have no other macros running. It is the GetObject Line that creates the background process but the background process does not end upon quitting the application

Comment: Then something is holding the file open. .xlsm are supposed to contain macros. You don't need to quit - all this is automatic. So no closing anything. No setting anything to nothing.